# Webpack. Сборка нескольких CSS отдельные файлы

Tags: webpack2, node-sass

Есть проект angular2, вот часть его структуры

[image: Структура проекта]

Стоит задача собрать проект при помощи webpack2. Причём собрать нужно так, чтобы получилось 2 файла css (например site.css и cms.css) и один файл с JS.
Стили в проекте лежат в отдельных папках и не импортируются в компонент, они после сборки должны подключаться в index.html. Так сделано специально, чтобы не использовать ExtractTextPlugin (такое условие).

С вебпаком я практически не работал. Есть какие-нибудь предложения как это реализовать?

Comment: К вопросу не относится - но не могли бы подсказать название IDE?

Comment: IDE называется VS Code